# Stuck with ignoreContentType in retrofit

Tags: android, jsoup, retrofit, retrofit2

i was using Jsoup, like next:

```
Jsoup.connect(apiURL + "/link")
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .execute()
                    .body();
```

but now i need to use retrofit 2 and I am stuck with **ignoreHttpErrors** and **ignoreContentType**...

any ideas how to provide that in retrofit 2??? Thanks!